# ASP.NET Charting Control Transparency

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, asp.net-charts

I'm working with the ASP.NET Charting Library and I've got it generating a pie chart but I'm having a problem configuring it to generate the pie chart with semi-transparent slices. If you look at the image you'll see what I'm talking about. Of the 4 pie charts the top 2 and the bottom left chart have the pie slice transparency I'm talking about.

[image: Charting Control Image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/chart/step2.png))</sub>

What settings of the chart do I tweak to render the slices with a certain % of transparency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try assigning the color of the series to a color with alpha transparency, like so:

```
Chart1.Series(0).Color = Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0) //transparent red
```

Taken from [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/MSWinWebChart/thread/519f75de-909d-4933-bbc6-dad434b85544).

Answer (score 1):

This the ultimate solution for both cases - one color per series or palette charts:

```
myChart.ApplyPaletteColors();

foreach (var series in myChart.Series)
{
    foreach (var point in series.Points)
    {
        point.Color = Color.FromArgb(220, point.Color);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Series["SeriesName"].Color = Color.FromArgb(180, Color.Blue);
```

Where 180 defines the "transparency level", which must be between 0 to 255.

You can use semi transparent palettes.

Refer to:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexgor/2009/10/06/setting-microsoft-chart-series-colors/

Answer (score 0):

Solution for color per serie and even for transparent palette:

Chart1.Series(0).Color = Color.FromArgb(200, Chart1.Series(0).Color)