# Default 3D chart transparency with ASP.NET Chart Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, asp.net-charts

like two guys before me [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465230/asp-net-charting-control-transparency/3415219#3415219) and second one [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117583/styling-the-asp-net-charting-controls) I have difficulty with 3D chart.

How to force them to be transparent like this picture:
[image]

taken from 3D Area chart example shipped with **ASP.NET Chart controls**. This chart has **ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel** pallete, but is transparent.

I have also 3D chart with **ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel** palette, but is not transparent and I still cannot found way how to make it transparent like example chart. (After examining example markup and codebehind):

[image]

The only way I've found is to set the color of series with alpha channel for transparency, or use color palette with transparent colors (for example **ChartColorPalette.SemiTransparent**) but there must be some other default way which I'm missing.

Reason I really need this to know is that I'm creating graphs without any code behind just using markup, so I'm finding it a little bit redundant to create code snippets only because of this.

Thank you very much for any answers.

Edit: **I'm using .NET 3.5 version of ASP.NET charts.**

Comment: I can't even get it in 3D. I enabled 3D but it doesn't draw 3D, just the same flat chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd same problem here. Solved using this:

```
// After all series manipulation, add this
chart.ApplyPaletteColors();
foreach (var serie in chart.Series)
    serie.Color = Color.FromArgb(220, serie.Color);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you're on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465230/asp-net-charting-control-transparency) thread too.  Unfortunately, you do need to use colors with an alpha channel in order to set transparency AFAIK

[Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20160227164615/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/alexgor/archive/2009/10/06/setting-chart-series-colors.aspx) a good overview of the palettes available and some basics on manipulating them

My guess is that you could create a new palette by iterating over the colors in the bright pastel palette and adding an alpha channel - if you do this in a global static, perhaps as part of your webapp init logic, you should be able to reference it pretty easily -  if you don't want to have *any* codebehind, you ?may? be able to databind your custom palette to the CustomPalette property, but I can't say with certainty.

Comment: Exatly this I'm doing right now. But ... I have not discovered any standard palete colors manipulation in 3D example, which has bright pastel colors, but IS ALSO transparent. So there must be some way.

Answer (score 1):

If you do use palette, and not one color per series, you have to set color for every point:

```
myChart.ApplyPaletteColors();

foreach (var series in myChart.Series)
{
    foreach (var point in series.Points)
    {
        point.Color = Color.FromArgb(220, point.Color);
    }
}
```